# How to access private instance variable of super class from another class or subclass in java?

Tags: java

I have a jpanel and some components(JButton) and now I want to access that button from another class. I want to disable/enable that button from another class. The button variable is private. If I extend will I able to access? Is it possible to use super keyword? I have tried some way but it is not working. Please give some suggestion.

Comment: What do you think `private` means and how it is supposed to work? Would not be very private if everybody could access it.

Comment: No.  If you need to access it from a child, then it needs to be `protected`.  If you need to access it in an unrelated class, then it needs to be `public`.

Comment: would you please give some examples?

Comment: Click on the first duplicate.